# On the fly java compiler in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an online java editor. I need the functionality that enables me to report the compilation errors to the user on clicking submit if there are any. 
I'm curious to know if there are any javascript libraries out there that I could use off the shelf to do this.

Comment: You really want to build a JVM in javascript?

Comment: Well not a JVM but a Java compiler.

Comment: Yeah, I think there's no big difference - after having it "compiled", there is not much work to execute it (unless you really create binaries)

Comment: @HarshalPandya - did you ever find a compiler in JS?

Answer (score 2):

Take the text and call javac on it on the server side, send back the results in some structured way and display on the client side

Comment: That is exactly how I have implemented it at the moment. I just wanted to know if there was anyway I could save the calls to the server.
As in make the call only if the code is free of compilation errors.